# systemctl start postgresql-13 start failed

Tags: database, postgresql, server, centos, freedesktop.org

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8JXI.png)

I am trying to install netboxtool but when i try to start postgesql it giving me below errors.Selinux already disabled.

```
 [1][root@it ~]# systemctl start postgresql-13 Job for postgresql-13.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql-13.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. [root@it ~]# journalctl -xe -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit session-6.scope has finished starting up.
-- The start-up result is done. Apr 09 19:32:45 it sshd[2686]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) Apr 09 19:32:45 it systemd-logind[641]: New session 6 of user root. -- Subject: A new session 6 has been created for user root -- Defined-By: systemd -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel -- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
-- A new session with the ID 6 has been created for the user root.
-- The leading process of the session is 2686. Apr 09 19:32:50 it polkitd[1383]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2714:612049 (system bus name :1.38 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallbac Apr 09 19:32:50 it systemd1: Starting PostgreSQL 13 database server... -- Subject: Unit postgresql-13.service has begun start-up -- Defined-By: systemd -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit postgresql-13.service has begun starting up. Apr 09 19:32:50 it postgresql-13-check-db-dir[2720]: "/var/lib/pgsql/13/data/" is missing or empty. Apr 09 19:32:50 it postgresql-13-check-db-dir[2720]: Use "/usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup initdb" to initialize the database cluster. Apr 09 19:32:50 it postgresql-13-check-db-dir[2720]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql13-13.6/README.rpm-dist for more information. Apr 09 19:32:50 it systemd1: postgresql-13.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr 09 19:32:50 it systemd1: Failed to start PostgreSQL 13 database server. -- Subject: Unit postgresql-13.service has failed -- Defined-By: systemd -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit postgresql-13.service has failed.
-- The result is failed. Apr 09 19:32:50 it systemd1: Unit postgresql-13.service entered failed state. Apr 09 19:32:50 it systemd1: postgresql-13.service failed. Apr 09 19:32:50 it polkitd[1383]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2714:612049 (system bus name :1.38, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/A lines 2130-2166/2166 (END)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the default data directory `/var/lib/pgsql/13/data` is missing. Check if that exists and create it.

Comment: @Ghowtham /var/lib/pgsql/13/data this exist but inside data is empty which ls it.

Comment: @kaleemUllah ok. In that case first you have initialize the DB directory `/usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup initdb`  and start the service